# Detect when a section which contains a specific div changes class?

Tags: jquery

I have a page which contains sections, which in reality is a slider which rotates and when that happens the section class changes between `present`, `future` and `past`.

```
<section class="past"></section>
<section class="present"><div id="vs"></div></section>
<section class="future"><div id="vs"></div></section>
```

What I want to detect is when a section changes its class to `present` and the section contains a div called `#vs`. If the section that changes its class to `present` doesn't contain the div `#vs` nothing should happen.

How can I do this with jQuery and make it happen every time the sections class is changed?

Comment: Turn the problem on its head: instead of trying to listen to changes to the element's class, check what is actually changing the class instead. That function should ideally either (1) emit an event or have an API hook that informs any listener when a class in changed, or (2) accept some kind of predefined callback that is invoked when mutating the element's class.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also keep in mind that an `id` is unique to the document, and you have two `id="vs"`.  Things will not behave as you expect, and this is not valid HTML.

Comment: I don't know which event that changes the class, and I have trouble finding out. I cannot see anything when looking at the console. But if I check the `section` I can see the change happening.

Comment: You could possibly do this with a DOM Mutation Observer (leave you to research as it's a non-trivial subject)- but I also recommend finding what's changing the class and hook into that.

Answer (score 0):

After you commented that it was Reveal.js you're using, I took a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#api) to see if there were events to use.

I found a jsFiddle that showed Reveal.js initialization and modified it to use the `slidechanged` [event](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#slide-changed-event) to get the current slide object. [View that jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jayharland/gzboyxhn/).

The relevant piece of code:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
     if($(event.currentSlide).hasClass('example')){
          console.log('Slide with example class!')
     }
});
```

Comment: I use the reveal.js slider. https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/ I have tried looking for the event in the code, but I cannot make it out. I will try your solution!

Comment: I will update my answer. Using DOM Mutation Observer with Reveal.js is going to lead to headaches and trouble for you. Best to use the API Reveal provides here https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#api

Comment: Wow thank you, I am so sorry I didn't check there first! Thank you for helping me!